# STI ::find() fails in controller but succeeds in tinker

Tags: laravel, sti

I'm using [`MannikJ/laravel-sti`](https://github.com/MannikJ/laravel-sti) but the following code has a different behaviour in tinker and in a controller (assuming the definitions in `larevel-sti`'s documentation, with classes `Root`, `Sub1` and `Sub2`):

```php
Root::find(1234)
```

In tinker, it correctly returns an instance of `Sub1`. But in a controller, it returns `null`.

I get the correct instance in the controller if I replace the code with:

```php
Sub1::find(1234)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the maintainer (cf. [issue #1](https://github.com/MannikJ/laravel-sti/issues/1)), we found that the problem is that we use constructors in our objects but `laravel-sti`'s trait also does. Constructors are a known issue in PHP with traits…